# How to jumble a word from EditText and apply the jumbled word into a TextView

Tags: android

I need to know how to jumble a word entered into EditText.

The jumbled word will show in another TextView in the same interface.

I have tried to do this but I get a force close error. This is what I have tried within the button:

```
wordE = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry); 
jumble = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jumble);
Button link5Btn = (Button)findViewById( R.id.selected );
link5Btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
{
public void onClick(View v)
    {
jumbleMe(al);
}
```

Which calls the method:

```
private void jumbleMe( String word ){

al = wordE.getText().toString(); 
ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < wordE.length(); i++) {
    al.add(word.charAt(i));
}
Collections.shuffle(al);

jumble.setText( al.toString() );
}
```

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: `jumbleMe(al);` what is `al`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply al is just a variable which I haven't named properly:  EditText wordE;
 String al;
 TextView jumble;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some mistakes.

Try changing the code to:

```
    link5Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            jumbleMe(wordE.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

and

```
private void jumbleMe(String word) {
    ArrayList<Character> al = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordE.length(); i++) {
        al.add(word.charAt(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(al);
    String result = "";
    for (Character character : al) {
        result += character;
    }

    jumble.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help worked great, your a great person. Have a great day!